# changing my windows form design removes some unrelated code

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm having a strange issue that maybe being caused by my ignorance.

I have a `treeview` with an `.AfterSelect` and any time that i change the design of my form (in the deign view) the code gets removed for some reason.

here is my code

```
this.lstTreeView.AfterSelect += LstTreeView_AfterSelect; < this is the code that gets removed
this.lstTreeView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(194, 56);
this.lstTreeView.Name = "lstTreeView";
this.lstTreeView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 498);
this.lstTreeView.TabIndex = 6;
```

this is the code that it allows to work.

```
private void LstTreeView_AfterSelect(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode CurrentNode = e.Node;
        string fullpath = CurrentNode.FullPath;
        MessageBox.Show(fullpath);
        NrDirSearch(fullpath);

    }
```

if anyone can give me some advice on why the .AfterSelect is being removed that would be really helpful.

Comment: Does it do the same if you set up the event through the form designer?

Comment: can u share the whole code?

Comment: @DanielB https://justpaste.it/1ltam here is the full code to the designer.cs sorry it's not in a very readable format

Comment: @John sorry I dont know how to set up an event from the designer. Unless you mean the .Designer.cs file in that case this is what i did above where i just added in the code `this.lstTreeView.AfterSelect += LstTreeView_AfterSelect;`

Comment: Yeah but the windows forms designer sets itself up from the designer.cs so really any changes to it should be reflected in the designer when it is next opened. Indeed his is sometimes mandatory if you eg remove an eventhandler from your form.cs and the designer crashes because it can't find it

Comment: You should **never** touch `.Designer.cs` as this files are rewrited every time, when you save changes.

Comment: @adamWadsworth right click the control -> Property -> click the thunder icon

Comment: @skyoxZ Thanks for your help was exactly the issue i was having

Comment: ..dows forms designer builds itself directly from the contents of the designer. You might hence run into issues if you edit it in a text editor while the designer is open(changes will be lost) but a developer shouldn't be told never to edit it. It is safe to edit, just that one has to appreciate that the forms designer edits it too, so changes could be lost (as you'd expect if you have two things open editing the same file at the same time)

Comment: @CaiusJard don't be rude, as mentioned in summery of `InitializeComponent()` method in `.Designer.cs` file: _do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor_. Try this: add a button click event handler using the designer (add a new button, double click), save all, now select your button in designer (single click) open an `Events` tab in `Properties` window and remove the name of event handler right to the `Click` event. Now save all and, wow, no crashes, no "blue and white" screens and it also removes unused event handler from code-behind! How this can be possible?

Comment: This is not news to me, as evidenced by the fact that I wrote it into my answer well before you made the same thing in your comment. If you've never seen a screen like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOaLc.png - editing the designer.cs file directly to remove/correct the offending lines is the fastest way out of this one and it's not a problem to do so. Unlike something like a dataset's code behind(which is generated from an xml and loses changes every time the custom tool is run) a forms designer.cs is safe to edit provides you close the forms designer first

Comment: @CaiusJard sure, I've never seen this screens, as I'm trying to never shoot my leg, read the docs and work with Designer in a way it should be. What you telling to do (remove assigning an event handler from `.Designer.cs` file) is more a "disaster recovery", then a "normal situation" and you, as a developer, should be all means try to avoid this situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you:

- in the windows form designer, click the tree view to select it
- in the properties grid click the lightning bolt and scroll to find the AfterSelect event
- right click the name AfterSelect and choose reset
- hit save all
- Close out of the soution entirely/shut down visual studio
- restart/reload the solution
  Go back to the AfterSelect event as above, the box for which should be empty
- click the drop down and choose your existing event handler
- save all, quit and restart vs and check that the setting stayed

If you're finding it didn't stick, check that you don't have your designer open in another program e.g. A text editor that keeps autosaving an old version of the file that lacks the event handler?

Incidentally, the above process is how you add event in Design view - click the relevant control, lightning bolt, scroll to event wanted, double click the name of the event and you will be transported to your own code behind with a new named eventhandler created and ready to be filled

If you don't write any code in it, and go back to the designer and Reset the event as per the bulleted list instructions then your event handler method in your code will disappear. If you write code into the event handler then it is not removed when doing a reset, only empty handler methods are removed during reset

Side note: be careful with Undo if you see a message saying something like "performing this undo will cause a loss of work elsewhere" it usually indicates that the windows form design or designer.cs code will change as a result of actioning the undo

Designer files are safe to edit manually and it's sometimes necessary if the contents have gotten into a state where they are crashing the designer. I most often encounter this when deleting event handler s from my code that are still referenced in the designer. A screen appears saying a problem is preventing the forms designer from appearing, indicating the error line in the designer file. I have additionally in the past edited the designer directly to set large numbers of properties without the faff of using the designer - be mindful not to have a windows forms designer open at the same time as editing the designer.ca file because the forms designer will probably overwrite your changes. So long as you keep in mind that opening the same file in any two different editors at the same time can lead to conflict and loss of work, and take steps to ensure that edits in one editor are reflected in another before proceeding with further edits in the other editor, you'll be fine :)

Edit: having said that paragraph above, Mickey D made me realise an important point I'd overlooked:

The designer.cs file is read by the forms designer and uses to build the contents of the form, buttons, properties etc. As such if you are going to edit the designer.cs in a text editor you should limit your edits to only those things the forms designer can make use of, understand, represent and preserve when it next writes the file. Adding a line to set a button to enabled is fine. Removing a line that is causing it to crash is also good. Putting 27 methods that implement your entire program's database access strategy in is not a good idea as it will not be heeded or used to build the form when the designer reads the file and hence lost when the designer writes the file. If you're unsure of the difference between what will and won't be preserved stick to removing or fixing existing lines only rather than adding new lines of code

Comment: Thank you the lightning bolt and selecting after select work. it would appear that i shouldn't mess with the designer.cs files. i'm fairly new to winforms and most of the stuff online doesn't really tell you this stuff it just gives you code to run. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, probably following a tutorial that says "paste this into your designer.cs" is a good way of quickly setting up a form with all its controls and everything necessary to follow the tut, but you should avoid editing the designer file routinely while the forms designer is open as it will overwrite your changes with its in memory version. If you seek to exclusively use the forms designer to set things up like events and properties you won't run into any problems, but equally don't be afraid of editing the designer file to resolve problems that sometimes occurs (close the forms designer first)

Comment: What he said. :)  +1

Answer (score 0):

You should never<sup>[1]</sup> modify ***.designer.cs** files.   They are code generated.  Any changes you make are subject to being overwritten.

Instead either use the WinForms GUI Forms Designer to visually setup event handlers or you can do so in code in your form’s code-behind .cs file.

There are plenty of resources on the Net on how to use the WinForms designer.

---

<sup>[1] <sub>see Caius Jard's comment below for an exception to the rule that I concur with</sub></sup>

Comment: The only statement I take issue with here is "you should never edit a designer.cs" - it would be better couched as "you should always seek to avoid editing a designer.cs file while the windows forms designer is open". The files themselves are safe to edit and indeed sometimes necessary if the contents are crashing the forms designer. They shouldn't be edited routinely while the designer is open for risk that changes made will be overwritten by the in-memory version of what the designer is designing

Comment: @CaiusJard I agree with you in principle and though I would like to include that in the main answer, its perhaps better to keep such advice in the small print otherwise beginners will misinterpret the intention.  Editing the designer.cs file is an advanced operation and it is important that it is made clear that whilst its ok to remove code that is causing the editor to crash, that one does not include other code in such a way that can be overridden later.

Comment: That's a good point; only code that the designer will be interested in, should be included - adding in N lines of code that e.g. Set property X of every control on the form would be fine; the designer will read them, heed them and remember to write them out next time it regenerates the form. However, pouring heart and soul into the most beautiful algorithm for doing Z as an extension method is not something the designer will be interested in, heed or preserve and would present a loss of work risk. I'll improve my answer to include this point, nice one